# Select text in devextreme input element

Tags: html, typescript, select, devextreme

I use Devexpress with TypeScript an angular 4.
How can I select/highlight text in dx-text-box?

I try to use `(document.getElementById('id') as HTMLInputElement).select();` but I cannnot get near input fields becaouse it use devextreme wrapper.

Wraper look like this.

```
<dx-text-box _ngcontent-c1="" id="test" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-value="11:26" class="dx-texteditor dx-widget dx-textbox"> 
<div class="dx-texteditor-container"><input autocomplete="off" class="dx-texteditor-input" type="text" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="textbox">
<div data-dx_placeholder="" class="dx-placeholder dx-state-invisible">
</div><div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container"></div></div></dx-text-box>
```

Comment: I found a solution       (document.getElementById('id').getElementsByTagName('input')[0] as HTMLInputElement).select();

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have defined your input with following div

```
<div id="myText"></div>
```

You would than instantiate the dxTextBox like this

```
var myTextBox = $("#myText").dxTextBox({value: "Select this text"}).dxTextBox("instance");
```

Now that you have the instance you would acces its input element as such

```
var myInput = myTextBox.element().find('input');
```

You can now call the select on your input.

```
myInput.select();
```